# How to work with OWL API?

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I have an OWL file that contains the model of a Person. It is a very simple ontology. 3 classes: Person, House, Car and some object relations. A Person `lives_in` a house, a Person `drives` a Car. 
Secondly, I've done an enquete that asks particpants for their name, their house type and the brand of their car. The replies look like this:

```
+--------------+----------+--------+
| Name         | House    | Car    |
+--------------+----------+--------+
| Eric         | Villa    | Audi   |
| John         | Bungalow | Volvo  |
| Marc         | Terraced | BMW    |
+--------------+----------+--------+
```

Now, the question. How do I bring my enquete data to the ontology? I've been told to use OWL API (EDIT) as my ultimate goal is to clusters the instances in the ontology. But I'm not quite sure where to start. As you might suspect, I'm completely new to ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

OWL API tutorials for starters are available [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki)

However, before you make a choice of APIs, it is important to understand what are your requirements. You mention a query in your question - have you decided whether you need to use a query language in your code, such as SPARQL? Do you need OWL or OWL 2 for your ontology?

OWL API does not support SPARQL, at present, and supports OWL 2. Apache Jena supports SPARQL and does not provide OWL 2 support, only OWL.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to cluster the persons in an finite number of clusters. Each cluster as homogeneous as possible.

Comment: OK, so OWL API is a suitable choice, it has been used for clustering here https://github.com/elenimikro/rio

Comment: I've set up my ontology using OWL API. I've implemented a basic Hierarchical and Partitional Clustering Algorithm of my own. Now I'd like to test different similarity measures (Relation/ Taxonomy similarity) so I started looking for some kind of Machine Learning Library in Java. I've found Weka is quite popular. Do you know about it? I believe RIO can also help but as I've not yet found documentation I'm a bit sceptical.

Comment: Weka and Mahout implement a number of clustering algorithms, however, as far as I'm aware, they do not have adapters for OWL input; you will have to write the adapter between your code and Weka yourself, in order to have the input format Weka requires.

Comment: I'm going slightly off-topic here but maybe one more question. What metric would you recommend to quantify the quality of my clustering. I'm using Silhouette when I have no labels and was thinking of ARI in the case I have labels (I've generated data from which I know the righ cluster a priori). Are these good metrics to use in ontology-based clustering?

Comment: Both could work, but it's really up to the actual application you need to cluster for, i.e., does it create valuable information for the calling system? I would try as many as feasible to get an idea of which one is best for your actual scenarios.